# Deleted root site

Tags: powershell

I have accidentally deleted my root site. I thought I was in a subiste and deleted it.

With powershell

```
GET-SPDeletedSite
```

I see

```
WebApplicationId   : 9fdb1d8c-19c1-43e5-99ea-6afbae62d2b9
DatabaseId         : 207d9679-3d68-4620-8865-e6dc75b7a17f
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 8875c48f-699d-4b37-8038-fbfd1f32a47c
Path               : /
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://mysite/
DeletionTime       : 3/28/2014 8:12:53 AM
```

that the site is there.
But how to restore it?
If I try

```
 Restore-SPDeletedSite -Identity 8875c48f-699d-4b37-8038-fbfd1f32a47c
```

I get:

> Restore-SPDeletedSite : Unable to find the specified file.
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + Restore-SPDeletedSite -Identity 8875c48f-699d-4b37-8038-fbfd1f32a47c
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...toreDeletedSite:
>          SPCmdletRestoreDeletedSite) [Restore-SPDeletedSite], FileNotFoundException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreD
>          eletedSite

How can I restore my site?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I am currently using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.

Comment: Similar issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/74f4202d-370e-4726-83c0-1490078a8844/restorespdeletedsite-and-removespdeletedsite-throws-unable-to-find-the-specified-file-error?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: what you get when run the get-SPDeletedSite "/"? and also make sure your database is not locked and you did not created the root site collction?

Answer (score 3):

> The Site Recycle Bin feature is newly introduced in Service Pack 1 for
>   SharePoint 2010, if you haven't installed SP1 for your SharePoint 2010
>   when you deleted the site collection, you need to restore the content
>   database, here are two articles about this.
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/06/30/sharepoint-2010-sp1-site-recycle-bin-ui-experience.aspx
>
> http://angler.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/sharepoint-server-2010-sp1-cool-feature-restore-deleted-site/

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6fed579d-62f6-4789-8ac0-88c236171b2f/restore-root-deleted-sitecollection)